# Lua require package doesn't work

Tags: lua

After upgrading my torch package, everything works well on the prompt, but, when I try to write my script and run it via command line, every require package won't work. And I am having the same message for all the package, like for example with `require 'torch'`

```
module 'torch' not found:
    no field package.preload['torch']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/torch.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/torch.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/torch.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua'
    no file './torch.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/torch.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/torch.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/torch.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './torch.so'
```

Comment: still doesn't work, I get this error message:

lua: error loading module 'libpaths' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so':
 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so: undefined symbol: luaL_register
stack traceback:
 [C]: in ?
 [C]: in function 'require'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/paths/init.lua:1: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:12: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 CNN_Model.lua:8: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: Instead of running it via `lua <file>`, use `lua5.1 <file>`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. But, when I use the csvigo, the load function doesn't want to work, any suggestion. This time, I get this error message:

Comment: lua5.1: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/csvigo/File.lua:103: module 'ffi' not found:
 no field package.preload['ffi']
 no file './ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/ffi/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ffi/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/ffi/init.lua'
 no file './ffi.so'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ffi.so'
 no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/ffi.so'
 no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/ffi.so'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'

Comment: stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'require'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/csvigo/File.lua:103: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/csvigo/File.lua:97>
 (tail call): ?
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/csvigo/init.lua:77: in function 'load'
 test.lua:24: in main chunk
 [C]: ?

Comment: `ffi` only works with LuaJIT, so try `luajit` instead of `lua5.1`.

Comment: @siffiejoe Thank you, everything works.

Comment: Someone compile the general idea in the comments into an answer so we can consider this "Answered"